# sh.status() error processing query: ns=config.mongosTree

Tags: mongodb

if I run sh.status in mongos I get the error:

```
assert: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "error processing query: ns=config.mongosTree: ping $gt new Date(1532712420740)\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n No query solutions",
        "code" : 2
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:290:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1312:5
printShardingStatus@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:611:13
sh.status@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:78:5
@(shell):1:1

2018-07-27T11:28:05.644-0600 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "error processing query: ns=config.mongosTree: ping $gt new Date(1532712420740)\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n No query solutions",
        "code" : 2
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:16:14
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:290:5
DBCollection.prototype.aggregate@src/mongo/shell/collection.js:1312:5
printShardingStatus@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:611:13
sh.status@src/mongo/shell/utils_sh.js:78:5
```

I reinstalled all mongo-enterprise packages but still the error persist, all the shards are working correctly, since I can perform find from mongos.

thanks

Comment: the mongo version is 3.2.20

Comment: I have 3 servers, on each server y have a mongod instance (3 shards and in each node have 1 replica set) I check and the sharding is working ok since I can perform inserts and find via mongos, but if i execute sh.status() I get the error described before, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same issue. 
It was becuase [notablescan](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/parameters/#param.notablescan) property enabled in my mongo config servers. After disable `notablescan` for config servers, command is working fine. you can check status of `notablescan` by running this command.

```
db.adminCommand( { getParameter: 1, notablescan: 1 } )
```

Output would be like below if `notablescan` is enabled.

```
{
  "notablescan": true,
  "ok": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I am able to see that you are getting the exit error `code : 2`

As MongoDB documented [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/exit-codes/) The error `code :2`  signifies The specified options are in error or are incompatible with other options.

As per MongoDB documentation [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/sh.status/) The **`sh.status()`**, When run on a [mongos](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongos/#bin.mongos) instance, prints a formatted report of the sharding configuration and the information regarding existing chunks in a [sharded cluster](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/glossary/#term-sharded-cluster). The default behavior suppresses the detailed chunk information if the total number of chunks is greater than or equal to 20.

For further your ref [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/sh.status/) and [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/view-sharded-cluster-configuration/)